# Why? - Constructing a list of dictionaries from a loop doesn't work unless the dictionary is recreated on every iteration

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, pass-by-reference

I was really stumped to find that creating a list of dictionaries from a loop does not yield the expected results unless the dictionary is recreated on each iteration.

The following examples are contrived and just serve as a minimal repex.

**Two things that do work as expected:**

```
l = list()
for i in range(1, 4):
    d = dict()  # dict recreated on every iteration
    d['index'] = i
    l.append(d)
print(l)

print([{'index': i} for i in range(1, 4)])
```

They both print:

```
[{'index': 1}, {'index': 2}, {'index': 3}]
```

**The thing that does not work as expected:**

```
d = dict()  # dict created once only
l = list()
for i in range(1, 4):
    d['index'] = i
    l.append(d)
print(l)
```

Produces:

```
[{'index': 3}, {'index': 3}, {'index': 3}]
```

I'd have expected that the existing dictionary's value referred to by `index` would simply be overwritten on every pass and then added to the list and that I'd get a little performance improvement (in reality the dict is much larger).

It almost appears as if `l.append` just added references instead of passing values.

Am I missing something embarrassingly obvious?

Comment: Python only works by reference (to simplify).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other people said,Python will pass the reference.But you could do like:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    d['index'] = i
    l.append(d.copy())
```

To get the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

"It almost appears as if `l.append` just added references instead of passing values.": That's it; you didn't miss anything.